# Run a security scan on WordPress site that has .htaccess password

Tags: security

Firstly, I don't know the correct term for what this password thing is. I think it's just a line in .htaccess, that prevents bots or unauthorized access to a staging environment, but it also breaks some other functionality from time to time. It's possible the password is not in .htaccess. I don't have access to it, and I cannot disable it.

I've tried 2 popular security plugins to run a scan on my site (am I allowed to say their names?), but they run into errors such as:

"The scan has failed to start. This is often because the site either cannot make outbound requests or is blocked from connecting to itself."

"SiteCheck error: Unable to properly scan your site. 401 Unauthorized"

Is there another "tool" that will run a scan without me disabling the password? (am I allowed to ask for suggestions on WordPress "tools"?)

Comment: Don’t use such plugins. They are only plugins - if your site is already infected, then someone is able to modify its code - so he’ll be also able to modify behavior of these plugins (I’ve demonstrated this many times on WordCamps). And no - there is no automatic way of checking of code of the site is secure - simple `mail($a, $b, $c)` can be secure or insecure - depends on a, b, c... So these using these plugins is just waste of time and resources - and even worse - you’ll have to spend a lot of time to delete all the garbage they leave in your DB and on your server...

Comment: The site isn't infected. As a precaution, I would like to know if any plugin files or core files are definitely different from what they should be. My alternative (which I often do) is to manually look through files for anything that looks blatantly suspicious. Would you like to estimate how efficient this process is compared to a security scan (even if the the scan is going to give me false negatives some of the time)?

Comment: Using such plugin won't secure anything. You can trust these scanners as long as the site is clean. If it gets infected, scans can show anything. So you may presume, that these scans will always show that your site is safe - so they're useless... On the other hand, security plugins are the plugins with the highest count of vulnerabilities in their code and they completely kill performance of your site. So no - you don't want to use them (even, if they look like such a great choice)...

Comment: I am talking about if I copy a website into a staging environment and just want to run a scan one time and then delete the plugin. I don't have a false sense of security and my question has nothing to do with how good a security plugin is at finding malicious code. I just want to run a scan in a matter of minutes so that if there is badly written malicious code it might be identified. I literally couldn't care less if 10%, or 50%, or 90% of the time, it fails to detect malicious code that is indeed there.

Comment: I will agree with you on the lack of usefulness of such plugins, but still, my question has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Installing the plugin harms your site already - all of these plugins leave a lot of trash on your server and huge amount of options that will be autoloaded even after you remove the plugin.

Comment: And back to your question - I don't believe you will get any useful answer, because it's off-topic in here to discuss third-party plugins...

Comment: I've probably found more than 10 infected websites throughout the years just by browsing through the files for anything that looks out of place. You'd be surprised at how easy is to find some of these hacks. When I do find them, I often install a security plugin just to see what happens, and it normally finds the files. Sure, it doesn't clean all the back doors, but it often can see that there's an issue.

Comment: No, I woudn't be suprised, because I've demonstrated many times how easy it is to cheat such plugins. And yes - malware very often does exactly that. Yeah - one of the things I do commercially is cleaning websites - for example in cases, when Sucuri is unable to help... So no, I really don't recommend to use such plugins at all, as they give you only illusion of security...

Comment: I agreed with you on the illusion of security 100%, but again, its not my question.

Comment: Yes - and your question has nothing to do with WP. You ask how to make some third-party plugins work - and that is off-topic, sorry... And no - these scans won't work if the site is behind BasicAuth, because they won't be able to get the site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The parent directory (which I don't have access to) uses htpasswd, but I can override this for my directory only by adding

```
Satisfy Any
```

to .htaccess. This fixes the issues I was having. I'm ok with disabling the authentication temporarily to run a scan and turning it back on afterwards.

More info on disabling htpasswd here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1431399/7220351